# How to insert data into table. But table creating at runtime, is it possible or not?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure p1(p_deptno in number)
is
type t is table of emp%rowtype
index by binary_integer;
v_emp t;
begin
execute immediate 'create table test as select * from emp where ename is null';
select * bulk collect into v_emp from emp where deptno=p_deptno;
for i in v_emp.first..v_emp.last
loop
insert into test(empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno) values (v_emp(i).empno, v_emp(i).ename, v_emp(i).job, v_emp(i).mgr, v_emp(i).hiredate, v_emp(i).sal, v_emp(i).comm, v_emp(i).deptno);
end loop;
exception
when value_error then
dbms_output.put_line('Give proper deptno');
end p1;
/
```

I am getting this error:

> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid query? `'create table test as select * from emp where ename is null';` Have you tried to execute it not in the stored procedure?

Comment: Suppose i want to create table at runtime and insert data at runtime into table using store procedures and dynamic sql .its possiable or not?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to make sure that your code is working.

Comment: What is table `test`?

Comment: @thescion - yes, `CREATE TABLE TEST AS SELECT * FROM EMP...` is a perfectly valid CREATE TABLE statement. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#i2095331 and follow `create_table` to `relational_table` to `table_properties` and note that at the very end of `table_properties` you'll find `AS (subquery)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating the table at runtime you must use dynamic SQL to perform the insert. Another problem is that you're sucking that data into an in-memory table, then performing the inserts one-by-one. I suggest something like:

```
create or replace procedure p1(p_deptno in number) is
  type t is table of emp%rowtype
    index by binary_integer;
  v_emp t;
begin
  execute immediate 'create table test as select * from emp where ename is null';

  execute immediate
   'insert into test
      select *
        from emp
        where deptno = :1' USING p_deptno;
exception
  when value_error then
    dbms_output.put_line('Give proper deptno');
end p1;
```

You can still do the inserts one-by-one using dynamic SQL, but it seems like a waste of time and effort.

Best of luck.

Comment: Why not use a bind variable in your dynamic `insert` statement?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a stored procedure in Oracle all referenced objects (in your case table "test" and "emp") in that stored procedure are checked in advance at compile time for appropriate grants/ownership of the referenced object. As the object "test" doesn't exist at compile time there naturally aren't any appropriate grants/ownership for the owner of the stored procedure and you get the error that you specified. To remedy the situation you can put the insert statement in "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" statement just as @Bob Jarvis stated , this way the check doesn't happen at compile time but at run time and the check succeedes because the object is created at run time and exists along with appropriate grant/ownership.

```
  execute immediate 'insert into test select * from emp where deptno = '|| p_deptno;
```